# Ona (עונה) obligation timing details

Tags: marriage, rambam

Based on Rambam (Ishut 14) and Shu"A (EH 76).

If the husband is משועבד "enslaved" to his wife, and, say, his duty is twice a week, who decides when the "Ona" is performed?

Is the "Ona" like a debt; if several opportunities are lost do they all have to be "repaid"?  I saw Shevet Halevi (רכ) asking  a similar question: "If a Talmid Chaham misses his duty on Shabbos, is he still obligated to perform midweek"? But I could not understand if he answers it.

Comment: I edited your question. I hope you can accept the changes.

Comment: the husband decides, if he violated his obligation, he committed the sin (asai), repaying will not help

Answer (score -2):

[Rambam Hilchos Ishus 14 (1) from the Chabad website](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952888/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Fourteen.htm#footnoteRef1a952888) states:

> The [obligation of] conjugal rights(1) as prescribed by the Torah [is
>   individual in nature], depending on the strength of each particular
>   man and the [type of] work that he performs.

The note (1) there {*I do not know who the author is*} may help to answer your questions:

> (1) The very word onah - and its translation as "conjugal rights" -
>   conveys a fundamental conception with regard to the Torah's conception
>   of marital intimacy. Marital intimacy is not for the husband's sake,
>   but rather for his wife's. Onah also means "respond." A man should be
>   responding to his wife's desires and satisfying her wishes for
>   closeness.

It seems from here that the Ona is a response to the wife and is not treated as a debt.

Comment: No. You are reading halakha into a cute derash. It is true that he should try to satisfy his wife's needs and desires. That doesn't tell us whether if he fails to do so, he needs to do more in the future or not. || It also doesn't tell us about timing. If he says I am available any time except Tuesday night from the hours of 11:00-11:30, and she says that those minutes are essential, is he violating the mitsva? While he is supposed to filfill his needs, if she declines he is exempt. The question is if he offers day 1, and she declines, is he exempt.

Comment: Exactly! I'm glad you understood my question.

Comment: @Avrohom The question is very specific - if it is "for his wife's sake" who's setting the schedule? I edited the question to include Shevet Halevi's question.

Comment: first comment should read "supposed to **fulfill her** needs"

Comment: the author is Eliyahu Touger